# Software-based Static in Speakers

Tags: speakers, noise

I've been having this problem for quite a while and it's driving me crazy! There is a steady stream of static that comes out of my speakers whenever I play music or videos.

There's no static when nothing is playing. I've tested with two other sound cards and the static persists. It's not the speakers because when connected to another computer they're fine. It's not the cables either. And the weirdest part, if I play video with Media Player Classic - Home Cinema installed using LAV decoders, the static disappears.

Comment: What program is causing the static normally?

Comment: Anything that plays audio or video. Windows Media Player, Flash Player (YouTube), VLC, and even Windows Sounds (like the login sound). MPC-HC is the only thing that doesn't have static.